# How to set priority of interface implementation in Orchard?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac, orchardcms

I'd like to create a custom INavigationProvider in my module for Orchard CMS:

```
[UsedImplicitly]
LocalizedMainMenuNavigationProvider : INavigationProvider
```

But it seems that my implementation is not used by the IoC container (AutoFac I think), probably because there is already another module installed that provides an implementation that is used.

How can I enforce Orchard to use my implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu is built by **INavigationManager**, which takes an **IEnumerable< INavigationProvider >** as a parameter. It means that it takes all providers for a given menu name and merges their outputs. And this data is used to render the final menu.

Also make sure that your class is **public** - otherwise your implementation won't be registered.

If I were you I'd rather create a custom implementation of INavigationManager based on the default one (so not to copy/paste all the code). This is the only place where you get all menu items gathered from providers and are able to localize them.

HTH